# get string value out of observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have this function with an Observable, so I can use the contents of the file.

```
  readDocument(fileChangeEvent: Event) {
    return new Observable(obs=>{
        const file = (fileChangeEvent.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (e) => {
          obs.next(fileReader.result);
        }
        fileReader.readAsText(file);  
    })
}
```

I use the function for getting the content of a csv file as a string.

```
    this.readDocument(data).subscribe(documentvalue=>{
         var teststring = documentvalue;
      })
```

My Problem is, if i then try to use the string (for highcharts in my example) :

```
  this.readDocument(data).subscribe(documentvalue=>{
    self.chartOptions.data.csv = documentvalue;
  })
```

I get following error:

> Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'string'.

How can I get the pure String value out of a subscription/observable?

Comment: What line is throwing the error ?

Comment: the self.chartOptions.data.csv = documentvalue;

Comment: line 116 here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q8ubo3?file=src%2Fapp%2Foutput-graph.component.ts

Comment: `var teststring =   = documentvalue;` Typo with two `=` I suppose?

Comment: The stackblitz snippet is not giving the same error

Comment: The error I get in stackblitz is "Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'"

Comment: i just copied everything into stackblitz so i guess its probably the same type of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error I get is `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'`, which makes more sense than the error that you got.

Because there is no type information in the observable, it defaults to thinking that the observable emits empty objects `{}`. This can't be assigned to `self.chartOptions.data.csv` which is a string. To fix this, you need to explicitly give a type parameter to the observable and make sure that it emits strings. Here's code that fixes that:

```
return new Observable<string>(obs=>{
    const file = (fileChangeEvent.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    let fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = (e) => {
      obs.next(fileReader.result as string);
    }
    fileReader.readAsText(file);  
})
```